# Do new browsers optimize for loops differently?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was reading Nicholas Zackas' [High Performance Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X) in which he discusses optimizing a for loop by reversing it and minimizing its property lookups.

Instead of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
  processItems(items[i]);
}
```

You get:

```
for (var i = items.length; i--; ) {
  processItems(items[i]);
}
```

At the time of writing, the execution times were "*up to 50%-60% faster than the original*." Yet I created a [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/minimizing-for-loops) and in Firefox and Chrome I've noticed that the *optimized* for loop is actually noticeably slower, especially in Firefox.

[image]

**Do newer browsers optimize for loops differently?** Is the most efficient way to write a for loop now simply the basic way?

Comment: Strange, I tested about the same yesterday and the fest one was the slowest...

Comment: Seems dangerously close to micro-optimisation to me.

Comment: To people having seen my answer before I deleted it : it was probably wrong and I'm too unsure about this to make a new one.

Comment: +1 Very interesting question, I can explaim Chrome's results but hopefully people who've read through the SpiderMonkey source will be able to shed some light on the subject. @Kolink this isn't about how to write fast code as far as I understand but how this optimization is being done

Comment: Purely speculation, but can't we expect browser writers to optimise for the most common/natural use cases? i.e. they will assume increasing sequential traversal and fully random access are typical, whereas the "optimised" version is atypical and relies on a pecularity of a particular implementation.

Comment: A lot of the micro-optimizations in that book are probably just wrong now. Javascript engines have advanced a LOT in the last three+ years.

Comment: [Reverse the setup](http://jsperf.com/minimizing-for-loops/7) and the test proves bogus.

Comment: @Steve-o I get the same results with reversed setup.

Comment: Here are the source codes by the way http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8f5b1f9f5804/js/src/jsarray.cpp https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/array.js

Comment: @dystroy the absolute performance result figures are different, they should be the same.  Ignore the relative figures between results.

Comment: Wow..4 runs in Chrome 26 right after each other and I get different results each time (in terms of what is better and by how much).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could include the test-case, as well, rather than forcing the browser to cast the answer to boolean?

```
var i, arr = [...];
for (i = arr.length; i > 0; i -= 1) { arr[i-1] = 1; }
```

First, your loop is casting the 0 as an end-condition, second, `arr[i]` where `i = arr.length` is undefined, which means that Chrome will de-optimize the loop in regard to accessing that array, due to implicit types, under the hood of Chrome.

So now, as far as Chrome is concerned, you've got two large de-optimizations happening in Zakas' use-case.

JavaScript engines have indeed progressed a very long way in the past 3 years, in regard to how they optimize things behind the scenes.
Now, it's less about writing code to trick the engine into optimizing better (which can now be counter-intuitive to the actual optimization-intelligence being built into modern browsers' JS compilers), and more about writing optimized code in the regular sense -- knowing which data-types to use, when, et cetera.

I think that you're going to find that if you try the test again, changing those two things that I recommend in the code-sample above, that while the numbers might not match exactly, they're going to be a lot closer to the forward performance.

Comment: In many cases, it's about using a pattern which the JIT can recognize.  For example, if the JIT can determine that your loop exit condition contains a bounds check, it can omit doing a bounds check on every array access inside the loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed. The other part of that is not stepping out of bounds in arrays, to begin with `i <= arr.length; arr[i];` would cause a de-op of the array in Chrome/V8 (not necessarily other engines), if `arr` was a non-sparse array holding integers, or to a lesser extent, holding only one data-type. Hitting that `undefined` at the edge of the array would mean that Chrome would convert the array into its slowest format (with added time-penalty for the actual de-op process). This is according to talks in the past ~12 months (like Google I/O), and given to change/improve, of course.

Comment: @Norguard I do not understand how this answers OP's question.  It doesn't explain the result variation between chrome and firefox. The question is about how array optimizations are done on either, and how/why are they being done differently. (Also, look at the jsperf he included, that _is_ the test case)

Comment: The descending version doesn't actually access `arr[arr.length]` as this answer claims.  (For a moment I agreed it did, but take a closer look)